# For $p, q$ prime, if $q$ divides an integer $n$ but $p$ does not, show that $\text{gcd}(n, p\cdot q) = q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For $p, q$ prime, if $q$ divides an integer $n$ but $p$ does not, show that $\text{gcd}(n, pq) = q$

This statement sort of reminds me of Euclid's Lemma, but I haven't been able to progress much.

I tried writing $n = kq$ for some integer $k$. Then we have $\text{gcd}(kq, pq)$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime. I don't really know how to progress from here.

Comment: q divides n and pq $\implies$ gcd(n,pq) divides q

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I believe the right hand part of what you wrote should be "$q$ divides $\gcd(n,pq)$" instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan:  Thank you for the correction.  I should have said q divides n and pq $\implies$ q divides gcd(n,pq).  If I could show also gcd(n,pq) divides q, I'd be done!

Comment: gcd(n,pq) divides n and pq; if it divided p it would be 1 or p, but it's not 1 since q divides it, so it would be p, but then we'd have p divides n, which it does not; so we can't have gcd(n,pq) dividing p, so it must divide q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: there are only $4$ divisors of $p\cdot q$.  Which could be $\gcd(n,p\cdot q)$?

Answer (score 1):

More generally for any $\,p,q\in\Bbb Z\!:\,$ $\, \color{#c00}{(p,n)}=1\,\Rightarrow\, (pq,n) = (q,n),\,$ because

$$ (pq,n) = (pq,nq,n)=(\color{#c00}{(p,n)}q,n) = (q,n)$$

This is indeed one form of Euclid's Lemma. The above proof works in any domain where gcd exists (where proofs using unique factorization [e.g. Robert's answer] may fail).